# Docker compose failing to run on Windows-2019 ADO build agent

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-devops

We're using the Windows-2019 vmImage for our hosted build agents, which have both docker and docker-compose installed (https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md).

But as soon as we run any docker-compose command (whether 'up' or 'down' or other), we immediately hit an error with little feedback:

```
Error: 3/30/2020 2:09:06 PM: 
At D:\a\1\s\psakefile.ps1:16 char:5 +     docker-compose down +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [<<==>>] Exception: Removing network s_default
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Any ideas? Do we need to initialise something on the build agent first so that docker-compose works? Everything works locally tested against numerous machines.

Comment: Isn't it much better if you could update with your psakefile.ps1 file? Hosted Win-2019 image indeed support docker compose.

Comment: At its bare bones, it's literally just "docker-compose down" and it still fails

Comment: If this, it's succeed for me..since I just run a simple docker command in powershell task